# Is there a way to arrange data like this in SQL? I'm open to suggestions

Tags: sql

My data is like this:

[image]

And I want my data to be like this:

[image]

Is there a way to query it in SQL? I'm a beginner in SQL so I only know basic querying statements.

Comment: You would do this with `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` - but arguably that's an incorrect use of SQL because SQL is built entirely around a presumption of arbitrary rows with fixed, well-defined columns - _and not_ arbitrary columns (case in point: SQL does not support dynamic columns: `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` still requires you to explicitly name columns: it won't generate column-names from unknown data values, for example.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The Exact SQL Select statement you're after would be quite redundant and unnecessarily convoluted. SQL is used when the data in your "Columns" are better defined and less arbitrary. From the sounds of it this isn't well normalised and you'd need to break it into multiple tables. In general, each selected statement should be tied to a separate datetime, or have multiple select statements give you many views.

If this is what you're after, look into Excel.
[Made in Excel | But regardless illustrates the point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM7AE.png)

Also, without a database design sheet or reference to the CREATE statement used to formulate your tables - it's very difficult to provide you with anything resembling relevant syntax. We don't know where even to begin. Please provide more info!

If you're formatting your data like that you probably should be using something like simpler Excel and .csv rather than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As you have *definite* number of columns (age groups and genders), one - simple - way to do it is to use conditional aggregation. For example:

```
SQL> select
  2    sum(case when age_group = '18-25' then gender_count else 0 end) "18-25",
  3    max(case when age_group = '18-25' and gender = 'F' then gender_count end) "F",
  4    max(case when age_group = '18-25' and gender = 'M' then gender_count end) "M",
  5    --
  6    sum(case when age_group = '26-30' then gender_count else 0 end) "26-30",
  7    max(case when age_group = '26-30' and gender = 'F' then gender_count end) "F",
  8    max(case when age_group = '26-30' and gender = 'M' then gender_count end) "M"
  9  from test;

     18-25          F          M      26-30          F          M
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       196        163         33        219        174         45

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked just like I wanted it to be.